# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2 in Spinner Item Selection

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, indexoutofboundsexception

I try to click on Spinner item and when i click on 1 Kg it crashed and error give

> Blockquote java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

Here is my code for Spinner and It listner :-

Here is my static array :-

```
 val values = arrayOf(
        "250 gm",
        "500 gm",
        "1 Kg",
        "2 Kg",
        "3 Kg",
        "4 Kg", "5 Kg", "6 Kg", "7 Kg"
    )
```

set ArrayAdapter :-

```
 ArrayAdapter(
        context,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        values
    ).also {
        it.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        holder.product_spinner_kg.adapter = it
    }
```

and this is Listner of this spinner:-

```
holder.product_spinner_kg.onItemSelectedListener =
        object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long
            ) {


                selectedQty = values[position]

                if (position == 0) {
                    holder.product_price.text =
                        "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 0.25)
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    holder.product_price.text =
                        "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 0.50)
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    holder.product_price.text =
                        "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 1.00)
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    holder.product_price.text =
                        "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 2.00)
                } else if (position == 4) {
                    holder.product_price.text =
                        "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 3.00)
                }

            }
        }
```

My Exception is :-

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
>           at com.maruti.marutisabji.adapter.user.ProductAdapter$onBindViewHolder$3.onItemSelected(ProductAdapter.kt:107)
>           at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
>           at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
>           at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:53)
>           at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)

This is My code Link Please check it:-
https://gist.github.com/maulikdadhaniya/c0e16a9a13d03e9b7abe2235a35e7324

Comment: what `items` array contains ?

Comment: @TejasPandya Items Contains
`private var items: ArrayList<ProductListModel>,`

Comment: does it contain any data ? where you filled it ?

Comment: Yes it has data of Product Name , Price , Brand , and i Filled threw API call in ProductActivity it hase List of Product with productAdapter. And this my question code is from Adapter code @TejasPandya

Comment: And when i click on 250 gm and 500 gm app is not crash but when i click on 1 Kg app getting crash

Comment: your error points towards array of `items`. so would be better if you attach the code of how you are filling it as well. you attached `values` array above but you are dealing with `items` array inside `ontitemSelected`

Comment: @TejasPandya I update my question and add link of my code please check it

Comment: Please don't just link to your code off-site. You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 3rd parameter name of `onItemSelected` `position` to `pos`. Because `position` is already used in your `onBindViewHolder` and when you use `items[position]` it use `position` of `onItemSelected` but you have to use the `position` parameter of `onBindViewHolder`.

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long){

    selectedQty = values[pos] // here you should use pos

    if (pos == 0) { // need to chnage also here and below conditions
        holder.product_price.text = "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 0.25)
    } else if (pos == 1) {
        holder.product_price.text = "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 0.50)
    } else if (pos == 2) {
        holder.product_price.text = "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 1.00)
    } else if (pos == 3) {
        holder.product_price.text = "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 2.00)
    } else if (pos == 4) {
        holder.product_price.text = "Rs. " + (items[position].price.toDouble() * 3.00)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yaa sure @Jakir Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest below code block to avoid such kind of `IndexOutOfBound` error:

Rather than accessing entity directly from array, we can user `AdapterView` to find out selected item based on position.

In your `onItemSelected()` listener method,

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    // We can retrive selected item from adapter using below approach, so that it never give out of bound error.
    selectedQty = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as? String 
    // Your rest of the code of else-if ladder also seems miscellaneous to me
}
```

Comment: @Jonas please provide details about what's the content in item array?

Comment: [https://gist.github.com/maulikdadhaniya/c0e16a9a13d03e9b7abe2235a35e7324] here is my code please check it

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to end with else block